# AJAX doesn't insert data into database

Tags: php, ajax

I have several advertisements. Each of them has a 'garage' button. If I click this button, it should insert his own userid and motorcycle id into the database. I think the insert method is good but something isn't good with the ajax. I get the success message back, but the data doesn't get inserted to my database.

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="upload-to-garage<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <div class="float-right">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" name="advert-id">
        <button type="submit" class="btn bg-transparent" name="garage"><i class="fas fa-warehouse fa-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Place to my garage"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#upload-to-garage<?php echo $row['id']; ?>").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "upload-to-garage.php",
            method: "post",
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            dataType: "text",
            success: function() {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

upload-to-garage.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("config.php");
// Add to garage
if (isset($_POST['garage'])) {
    $advertId = $_POST['advert-id'];
    $userid = $_SESSION['id'];
    $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO garage (userid, motorcycleid) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $userid, $advertId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}

?>
```

Just checked and if I skip the AJAX part and using the simple PHP, it works fine. So the problem is with the AJAX for sure, but can't see what.

Comment: What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: I've checked if it's because of the #upload-to-garage[id] but it seems work just fine. Also tried with a different ajax method, but still nothing.

Comment: I just checked if it works without AJAX and it does. So the problem is with the AJAX part for sure but I can't see what.

Comment: Use the console to see what you’re sending and receiving. I bet you’re not sending `$_POST['garage']`. Also, I would recommend sending back a json “status” value to test against in the success method. That would allow you to realize that the `if(isset($_POST['garage']))` branch was or was not taken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your event handler like this `$("form[id*=upload-to-garage]")` instead of using php code for ids and then use `$(this)` to refer current form.Also, when you use serialize function submit button value doesn't get send so you can attach that as well using `&parametername=somevalue`

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //form when submit
  $("form[id*=upload-to-garage]").submit(function(e) {
    console.log($(this).serialize() + "&garage=somevalue")
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "upload-to-garage.php",
      method: "post",
      data: $(this).serialize() + "&garage=somevalue", //use this here
      dataType: "text",
      success: function() {
        alert('success');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="upload-to-garage1">
  <div class="float-right">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="advert-id">
    <button type="submit" class="btn bg-transparent" name="garage"><i class="fas fa-warehouse fa-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Place to my garage">i</i></button>
  </div>
</form>
<form action="" method="POST" id="upload-to-garage2">
  <div class="float-right">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="advert-id">
    <button type="submit" class="btn bg-transparent" name="garage"><i class="fas fa-warehouse fa-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Place to my garage">i</i></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you  very much. The only thing I don't understand is the 'somevalue' part. What should I write there? Edit: And for some reason I get the 'success' alert twice. Why is that?

Comment: You just need to give any value there because at your backend you are checking isset so . Also, about two alert are there any other handler for same event?

Comment: Yeah, I had two. Deleted one of them and it's fine now. A last question: I have 'unique' for these rows in my database so if it once uploaded, it won't upload again, but how can I display an error message, that says 'it's already  in your garage'?

Comment: Put some query at your backend to check if that record already exist or not and then use `if(somecondition){ echo "inserted";} else{ echo "already there";}` so that echo will send back to ajax as response so inside sucess add `success: function(response) {` and then inside this do `alert(response)` to show that echo message sended from backend .